# Multiple CustomJSHovers mapped to one field Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

My Bokeh version is 2.3.1. I'm able to use the CustomJSHover to specify some javascript to execute on hover, with the input being a field (from a column data source). However, I'm trying to map different CustomJSHover's to the same field, and specify them differently in the HTML. An example snippet of what I have is

```
    customjs = CustomJSHover(code="""///do some javascript here on the value var.""")
    hover_points = HoverTool(tooltips="""
        <div $x{custom} id=$index style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial; color:white; background:black; padding:10px;">
            <div>
                <span style="font-weight:bold;">Name:</span>
                <span>@input_x{custom}</span>
        </div>
        """,
        formatters={
            '@input_x' :customjs
        },
        point_policy='snap_to_data')
```

This works great, but I want to have multiple custom formaters on input_x. If I try something like this

```
    c1 = CustomJSHover(code="console.log(1);")
    c2 = CustomJSHover(code="console.log(2);")

    hover_highlight_line = HoverTool(tooltips="""
    <div style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial; color:white; background:black; padding:10px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;">1</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;">@input_x{c2}</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">@input_x{c1}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    """,
    formatters= {
        '@input_x':c1,
        '@input_x':c2
    },
```

I only get the console log for c2. Is this possible to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After sleeping on it, I finally found out how to do this.

Within the bracket, you can map a prefix to a formatter. This is in the docs, but the doc's don't tell you how to use it. Within the CustomJSCode argument, you can access this prefix (or if you want just specify the name) with the format variable.

```
    c1 = CustomJSHover(code="""
        if(format == 'agg'){ return //do something with agg}
        else if(format == 'mean'){return //do something to get the mean}
    """)
    

    hover_highlight_line = HoverTool(tooltips="""
    <div style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial; color:white; background:black; padding:10px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;">1</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;">@input_x{agg}</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">@input_x{mean}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    """,
    formatters= {
        '@input_x':c1,
    },
```

If there is a better way to do this, please post an answer. Thanks.